# Bus Seat Reservation. I have no idea how to make the code exit the program when I enter a negative number.(Index 1 out of bounds for length 1)

Tags: java

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BusReservation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean response = true;
        String[] user_respo;
        String[] Rows = { "Row 1 ", "Row 2 ", "Row 3 ", "Row 4 ", "Row 5 ", "Row 6 ", "Row 7 ", "Row 8 ", "Row 9 ", "Row 10 "};
        String [][] table = 
        {
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
                {"  |*", "   *   ","   *  ", "   *  "},
        };
        do {
            System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation");
            String[] columns = { " ","Col 1",  "Col 2",  "Col 3",  "Col 4" };
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + columns[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
                System.out.print(Rows[row]);
                for (int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print("\t" + table[row][col]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
            user_respo = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            int row1 = Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]);
            int col2 = Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]);
            if (Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]) > 0) {
                table[row1 - 1][col2 - 1] = "   X  ";
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]) < 0 && Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Problem Exit!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        } while (response == true);
    }

}
```

When I input a negative number the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at BusReservation.main(BusReservation.java:42)"
I have no idea how to make it say "Progran Exit!" instead.

Comment: Unrelated, but some indentation would really make this easier to think about. What's the specific issue? You have a boolean controlling the loop, and you know the conditions necessary to exit the loop.

Comment: `else if (Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]) <= 0 || Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]) <= 0)` - Use or not and. Also consider zero as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter only one number (of any kind) then

```
user_respo = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```

will create an array of size 1, which in turn causes this to error:

```
int col2 = Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]);
```

because there is no element `1`; there is only `user_respo[0]`.

You should check for the exit condition first and break from the loop if so:

```
while (true) {
    // other code
    user_respo = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    if (user_respo.startsWith("-")) {
        break;
    }
    // other code
}
```